# How do I clone or copy an existing test case in a suite in VSTS?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, testcase

Reading up on [test different configuration](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/manual-exploratory-testing/test-different-configurations/%22test%20different%20configurations%22) article from Visual Studio. In the example, they were able to create multiple of the same test cases (same ID) and assign different configurations to them.

How would I create multiple copies of the same test case for a suite? I've tried looking for a clone button that was suggested, but I believe it's only under Test Manger, which I do not have. Then I tried "adding existing" test case, and nothing.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Copying a Test Cases is almost never the right solution.

Comment: @MrHinsh, to have two or three test cases with different configurations (Browsers and OS).

Comment: @Ed Blankenship, thank you for correcting the title.

Comment: If you just have different configurations you can apply those configurations to the same Test Case. This does not require you to copy... What are you having trouble with on https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/test/manual-exploratory-testing/test-different-configurations

Answer (score 4):

You don’t need to copy test cases work item, a test case with multiple test configurations will have corresponding test point.

For example, test case A have conf1, conf2 and conf3, then there are three test points of test case A and all of them will list in test suite (Test Plans > Select the test suite)

To manage test cases in Test hub in web access, you need to install [Test manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-testmanager-web) extension.

Regarding clone/copy test case work item, you can refer to these steps:

1. Go to Test > Test Plans > Select a test suite
2. Right click a test point/test case > Open Test case
3. Click … > Create copy of work item

[image]

4. After saving the new test case, you need to add to add it to test suite by clicking Add existing button to add an existing test case.

Comment: I figured out what I was doing wrong. I knew we could create configuration variables but didn't know about multiple test configurations. Thank you for your response!